# Ruby: how to parse e-mail mime from the stdin

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems, mime-types, mime-mail

Anyone know how I can parse the E-mail MIME from Ruby when the input is from STDIN? I have found a gem called "mail" which looks really nice but so far as I can see it's able to read a mail only from the file:

```
require 'mail'
mail = Mail.read('/path/to/message.eml')
```

This is how I'm testing it:

```
# First one is from stdin:
require 'mail'
mail = Mail.new($stdin.readlines)
p mail.from
p mail.to
```

returns:
nil
nil

```
# This one is from the file:
mail2 = Mail.new("my_email.txt")
p mail2.from
p mail2.to
```

returns:
nil
nil

```
# The same file but I'm using Mail.read:
mail3 = Mail.read("my_email.txt")
p mail3.from
p mail3.to
```

returns:
["test@gmail.com"]
["test2@gmail.com"]

STDIN I'm testing like:

```
# cat my_email.txt | ruby code.rb
```

So the method Mail.read works fine with my e-mail, but when I want to put my stdin to the Mail.read I have:

```
mail/mail.rb:176:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)
```

I know that I can save that file from stdin to the temp folder and then open it by Mail.read but I don't want to do this in that way since it will be slow.

The full url to the gem is: https://github.com/mikel/mail

Answer (score 4):

**readlines** returns an *array*... of lines! You might want to try **read** on **ARGF** which is the input provided by $stdin instead.

```
mail = Mail.new ARGF.read
```

See [the relevant documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html).

Comment: You right! I didn't think about it. It works now! :-)

Comment: @user3612491 remember that you can accept the most helpful answer (this is completely optional, but a nice way to say thanks)

Answer (score 2):

`IO#readlines` produces an array. You want a string there:

```
# readmail.rb
require 'mail'
mail = Mail.new(STDIN.read)
p mail.from
p mail.to

# mail.eml
From: bob@test.lindsaar.net
To: mikel@test.lindsaar.net
Subject: This is an email

This is the body

# command line
$ ruby readmail.rb < mail.eml
# => ["bob@test.lindsaar.net"]
# => ["mikel@test.lindsaar.net"]
```